# How acess the data inside a document triggered in cloud firestore? / Does this read charge?

Tags: javascript, firebase, compiler-errors, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to activate a cloud function when a user comments on a post. I want to access this commentarie via cloud function.

Example: A user comment in a post X:
'I want eat fish'.

I want to access via cloud function -> the post Id, commentarie Id and the data inside the commentarie ('I want eat fish')

I have the following cloud function:

```
exports.onCommentarie = functions.firestore .document('posts/{postId}/{commentaries}/{commentarieId}') .onCreate((context) => {
let postId = context.params.postId
let commentarieId = context.params.commentarieId
let data = context
console.log('O comentário do Id foi:', data)
console.log('o Id do post foi:', postId)
console.log('o Id do comentário foi:', commentarieId) })
```

if i use `.onCreate((change, context) =>` the console return error.

Can i acess the data via context? My context is returning:

> O comentário do Id foi: { data: QueryDocumentSnapshot { _ref:
>   DocumentReference { _firestore: [Object], _validator: [Object],
>   _referencePath: [Object] }, _fieldsProto: { comment: [Object], creatorId: [Object], creatorName: [Object], creatorPhoto: [Object],
>   date: [Object] }, _serializer: Serializer {
>   timestampsInSnapshotsEnabled: false, createReference: [Function] },
>   _validator: Validator { isFunction: [Function], isOptionalFunction: [Function], isInteger: [Function], isOptionalInteger: [Function],
>   isNumber: [Function], isOptionalNumber: [Function], isObject:
>   [Function], isOptionalObject: [Function], isString: [Function],
>   isOptionalString: [Function], isBoolean: [Function],
>   isOptionalBoolean: [Function], isArrayElement: [Function],
>   isOptionalArrayElement: [Function], isDeletePrecondition: [Function],
>   isOptionalDeletePrecondition: [Function], isDocument: [Function],
>   isOptionalDocument: [Function], isDocumentReference: [Function],
>   isOptionalDocumentReference: [Function], isFieldPath: [Function],
>   isOptionalFieldPath: [Function], isFieldValue: [Function],
>   isOptionalFieldValue: [Function], isFieldOrder: [Function],
>   isOptionalFieldOrder: [Function], isQueryComparison: [Function],
>   isOptionalQueryComparison: [Function], isQueryValue: [Function],
>   isOptionalQueryValue: [Function], isResourcePath: [Function],
>   isOptionalResourcePath: [Function], isSetOptions: [Function],
>   isOptionalSetOptions: [Function], isUpdateMap: [Function],
>   isOptionalUpdateMap: [Function], isUpdatePrecondition: [Function],
>   isOptionalUpdatePrecondition: [Function] }, _readTime: undefined,
>   _createTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1535341163, _nanoseconds: 46815000 }, _updateTime: Timestamp { _seconds: 1535341163, _nanoseconds:
>   46815000 } }, eventId: '168433e5-0a62-42a5-a7b4-dbd58f629661-0',
>   eventType: 'providers/cloud.firestore/eventTypes/document.create',
>   notSupported: {}, params: { postId: 'U4lpN89JeM8cSVl2sv95',
>   commentaries: 'commentaries', commentarieId: 'F85CRjInT1HPltEbbKJS' },
>   resource:
>   'projects/herot-eyes/databases/(default)/documents/posts/U4lpN89JeM8cSVl2sv95/commentaries/F85CRjInT1HPltEbbKJS',
>   timestamp: '2018-08-27T03:39:23.046815Z' }

if (change, context) returns error, how can I access the data inside this?!

This read count as a read in the bills?! I have to calculate this, as it would increase a lot the costs of server.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for the `onCreate()` trigger for Firestore is the following, as detailed [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created) in the documentation.

```
exports.createUser = functions.firestore
    .document('users/{userId}')
    .onCreate((snap, context) => {
      // Get an object representing the document
      // e.g. {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 66}
      const newValue = snap.data();

      // access a particular field as you would any JS property
      const name = newValue.name;

      // perform desired operations ...
    });
```

You are passing only one parameter in your code (`.onCreate((context) => {})`), so you **have to**:

1. modify it to pass the two parameters
2. modify `let data = context` to `const data = snap.data()` (or `const data = change.data()` if you use `.onCreate((change, context)`).

It is not possible to get the data via `context`.

> The context parameter provides information about the function's
>   execution. Identical across asynchronous functions types, context
>   contains the fields eventId, timestamp, eventType, resource, and
>   params.

Comment: Your answer seems right, BUT... That is what i tried, exactly that. And, as i said in the question, it didn't work. For some reason, putting (snap, context) makes a error. 
I resolved by just using context. using:

context.data.data()

Comment: Are you sure you modified `let data = context` to `const data = snap.data()`?

Answer (score 0):

[@RenaudTarnec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3371862/renaud-tarnec)'s answers seems to be a good one and the way-to-go for this kind of issues. Nonetheless, [@eeerrrttt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6550067/eeerrrttt) resolved the issueon their own by using `context.data.data()` instead of `context` for the `data` variable.